# Undefined index but can echo

Tags: php

I tried sending data `username` from JS (client side) to PHP (server side). The problem is I got `notice undefined index : username` in my PHP but I can echo the data. Here is my code:

#### JS

```
function showdatabase(){

   var username =localStorage.getItem('username');  
 //document.write(username);

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();   } else { // code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   }   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
       document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }   }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","dataquery.php?username="+username,true);  
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

#### PHP

```
<?php

include('connection.php');


$username=$_GET['username']; echo $username;

//query of database
$result =mysqli_query($mysqlConnection,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_ID LIKE '$username'");

echo "<table border='4'>  <tr>    <th> Full Name</th>     </tr>";

//read data from array from database.
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>"; echo "<td>".$row['nama_penuh']."</td>"; echo "</tr>"; }
?>
```

I'm new to programming, hope you all can help. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are you not calling/executing your `showdatabase()` function? I don't see it being called.

Comment: If you are new to programming, you should use new technologies - so no IE6 support, no queries without prepared statements, no mixing of php and html : ))

Comment: you havnt called your function yet ..:/

Comment: Why are you using JS to query the db when you could be using PHP and a prepared SQL statement to do so and keep it all in one language.

Comment: showdabase() is call when the page load using the onload() function:). my browswer dispplay the 'echo $username' in php but variable above it is undefined :(. @CodeLover

Comment: it's because localStorage.getItem('username') is null or undefined !

Comment: as @Dev'Hamz said ..localstorage.getitem('username') seems to return the null value ..

Comment: but localStorage.getItem('username') is not null. ive check it by putting an alert pop up after localStorage.getItem('username') and it appear the username value. :( @Dev'Hamz. help!

Comment: You need to add the variable "username" parameter in your function like that : showdatabase(username) { // ** Some stuff ** // }

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `username` in the parameter of the function `showdatabase` so :

```
showdatabase(username) {

   // ** Content of your function **//

}
```

And when you call your function username needs to be initialize :

```
<a href="javascript: showdatabase('John');">MyCall</a>
```